# How do I manually copy assemblies into the GAC?

Tags: windows-7, global-assembly-cache

I'm using Windows 7 Ultimate, trying to manually copy a file into the GAC. I tried using Windows Explorer but it promptly tells me "Access is denied". I tried using the command line with elevated permissions and it says the file was copied but I can't find the assembly anywhere.

I'm updating a third party spreadsheet component (GemBox) and the update process involves manually dropping the new version of the assembly into the GAC of the dev machine. Any suggestions?

Comment: A safer and easier way would be to download a newer setup for GemBox component and install it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could try installing it using gacutil:

```
gacutil -I yourassembly.dll
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find gacutil in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\x64

Answer (score 0):

GacUtil (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex0ss12c%28VS.80%29.aspx) from elevated command prompt?